# Implicit function theorem and differentiation

Tags: analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to do this exercise on Real Analysis topics. It's about implicit function and I don't know how to conclude anything. Here it goes:

*"Consider the equation $x^3 + y^3 - 3axy = 1$ where $a > 0$. According to the implicit function theorem, characterize the set $D$ of the points $(x,y)\in R^2$ where the equation defines a function $y=y(x)$. Then, calculate the point $(x,y)\in D$ which satisfies $y'(x) = 0$."*

I tried to think of three cases: the points $(x,0)$, $(0,y)$ and $(x,y)$ and I got to the condition $y^2\neq ax$. I thought this condition could define $D$, but then I found out the expression for $y'(x)$ and can't find its zero.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me answer the question. 
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know the statement of "implicit function theorem"?

Answer (score 1):

we get for $y=y(x)$ the first derivative as follows: $$3x^2+3y^2y'-3ay-3axy'=0$$ solving for $y'$ we obtain:
$$(3y^2-3ax)y'=3ay-3x^2$$ and finally $$y'=\frac{ay-x^2}{y^2-ax}$$ if $y^2-ax\neq 0$
for $y'(x)=0$ you get $ay-x^2=0$ and this can you set in your equation $$x^3+y^3-3axy=1$$

Comment: I see what you did there, but can for which points can we ensure the existence of an implicit function y=y(x)? And how do we find the point that satisfies y'(x) = 0?

Comment: @Diogo: Basically IFT says that if you are not dividing by zero in the above formula for $y'$, then you are ok - locally there exists an implicit function.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Maybe it's just me not seeing the simplicity of the thing, but I still have some doubts. We have to ensure that the equation is satisfied in each point and that df/dy is not zero. We can't just say that there exists an implicit function in the neighborhood of each x... Our set D must have some conditions on its points. For example, the theorem doesn't ensure there exists an implicit function in points that verify y^2-ax=0... I think it is not that simple.

Comment: @Diogo: You are only to apply the above formula for $y'$ at such points $P=(x,y)$ that A) are on the curve, in other words satisfy the equation $x^3+y^3-3axy=1$ and, B) where the assumptions of the IFT are satisfied, here $y^2-ax\neq0$. Is that ($D$ is a subset of the curve) what you were missing? Anyway, IFT guarantees you a horizontal tangent at $P=(x,y)$, when the following three conditions are met: 1) $P$ is on the curve, 2) $y^2-ax\neq0$, and 3) $ay-x^2=0$ (so the above formula gives $y'=0$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks a lot! I think that defines the set D I was looking for. One last question (and sorry for bothering you so much!): in the last question, I think we were supposed to find a specific value of x such that $y'(x)=0$. Is it possible to do so, or the only way of answering is to present the three conditions you just told me?

Comment: @Diogo: It may be possible to solve the system $ay=x^2$, $x^3+y^3-3axy=1$. It looks a bit hairy (being cubic and all). Usually this type of equation has $0$ in place of $1$, when we get the Foil of Descartes. Need to think about this one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks a lot! I'll think about it as well. If I get to any conclusion I'll let you know.